# Why are readObject and writeObject private, and why would I write transient variables explicitly?

Tags: java, serialization, effective-java

I am reading the chapter on Serialization in *Effective Java*.

1. Who calls the readObject() and writeObject()? Why are these methods declared private ?
2. The below is a piece of code from the book

   ```
   // StringList with a reasonable custom serialized form
   public final class StringList implements Serializable {
       private transient int size = 0;
       private transient Entry head = null;

       //Other code

       private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s)
           throws IOException {
           s.defaultWriteObject();
           s.writeInt(size);
           // Write out all elements in the proper order.
           for (Entry e = head; e != null; e = e.next)
              s.writeObject(e.data);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Is there any specific reason the variable `size` is declared as transient and then in the writeObject method it is explicitly written? If it were not declared as transient, it would have been written anyway, right?

Comment: If you are interested in writing your own serialization, have a look at Externalizable.  It is much the same effort but with more flexibility. (it was added later)

Comment: It's only an example to demonstrate how to do it. There is no specific reason here for 'size' to be transient.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

(1) The methods are not declared in any class or interface. A class, that implements the `Serializable` interface and requires [*special special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) those methods and the serializer/deserializer will try to *reflect* those methods.

This is one of the rather strange corners in Java where the API is actually defined in the javaDoc... But *if* the methods had been defined in an interface, then they *had* to be `public` (we can't implement an interface method an lock it by adding a `private` modifier).

*Why private* - the javaDoc does not give a hint. Maybe they are *specified* as private because no other class but the implementor is intended to use them. They are *private by definition*.

(2) The example simply shows *how* the special handling works. In this example, `size` is transient and will not be serialized. But now we introduce the special handler and this handler adds the value of `size` to the stream. The difference to the normal approach with non-transient fields could be the order of elements in the resulting stream (if it matters...).

The example could make sense, if the transient field was defined in a super class and a subclass wanted to serialize the value.

Comment: There's no 'should implement those methods' about it. Default serialization without custom readObject()/writeObjects() works perfectly well in the vast marjority of cases. You *can* implement them if you *need to.*

Comment: @EJP - yes, you're right, corrected the phrase. It's not a *should* but *must* in some cases.

Answer (score 18):

Apart from *should not be used by wrong parties*, here is another reason for the privacy of these methods:

**We don't want these methods to be overridden by subclasses**. Instead, each class can have its own `writeObject` method, and the serialization engine will call all of them one after the other. This is only possible with private methods (these are not overridden). (The same is valid for `readObject`.)

(Note that this only applies to superclasses which themselves implement Serializable.)

This way, subclasses and superclasses can evolve independently, and still stay compatible to stored objects from older versions.

Comment: On the contrary, `super.writeObject` makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: @TomášZato this way is used for classes implementing the Externalizable interface (which has public methods).

Answer (score 10):

About readObject()/writeObject() being private, here's the deal: if your class Bar extends some class Foo; Foo also implements readObject()/writeObject() and Bar also implements readObject()/writeObject().

Now, when a Bar object is serialized or deserialized, JVM needs to call readObject()/writeObject() for both Foo and Bar automatically (i.e. without you needing to class these super class methods explicitly).However, if these methods are anything but private, it becomes method overriding, and JVM can no longer call the super class methods on the sub class object.

Hence they must be private!

Answer (score 7):

The `readObject` and `writeObject` are called by the `Object(Input/Output)Stream` class(es).

These methods are (and must be) declared private (when implementing your own), proving/indicating that neither method is inherited and overridden or overloaded by the implementation. The trick here is that the JVM automatically checks to see if either method is declared during the corresponding method call. Note that the JVM can call private methods of your class whenever it wants **but no other objects can**. Thus, the integrity of the class is maintained and the serialization protocol can continue to work as normal.

And regarding the transient `int`, it's just taking control over serialization of the entire object serialization as such. However, note that technically it is not even **necessary** to invoke `defaultWriteObject()`, if all fields are transient. But i think it is still recommended to invoke it for flexiblility purposes, so that later you can introduce non-transient members in your class, preserving compatibility.

Comment: The methods are not part of `Object(Input/Output)Stream`, they are required for `Serializable` classes that need special handling for serialization / deserialization. `readObject()` and `writeObject(Object obj)` in the stream classes are `public final`.

Comment: +1; You can call private methods using reflection, which is how Java Serialization and other serialization generally do this sort of thing.  You need `defaultWriteObject` for super class fields as well. i.e. you might not have any non-transient field, but a super class might.

Comment: @Andreas - Yes, they are public final in OIS/OOS, but my impression was that the question was from an invocation point-of-view (on which types are they really invoked over).

Comment: @Saket Either they are public members of ObjectInput/OutputStream as per your first para., or they must be private as per your second para. You can't have it both ways. To avert an extended discussion I have edited your first para.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i remember that the serializable class is not in charge of super class. Every serializable class only serial the fields of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the transient variable, best way to understand as if why do we declare transient variable and later on serialize them in writeobject method is to check/analyze/debug readobject/writeobject methods of LinkedList/HashMap/etc classes.

This is generally done when you want to serialize/de-serialize the class variables in a pre-defined order and not rely on the default behavior/order.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a Class A which has reference to a Socket. If you want to serialize objects of class A you can't directly because Socket is not Serializable . In this case you write code as below.

```
public class A implements  implements Serializable {

// mark Socket as transient so that A can be serialized

private transient Socket socket;

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)throws IOException {
    out.defaultWriteObject();

    // take out ip address and port write them to out stream
    InetAddress inetAddress = socket.getInetAddress();
    int port = socket.getPort();
    out.writeObject(inetAddress);
    out.writeObject(port);
}



private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
                  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    in.defaultReadObject();
    // read the ip address and port form the stream and create a frest socket.
    InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress) in.readObject();
    int port = in.readInt();
    socket = new Socket(inetAddress, port);
}
}
```

Ignore any networking related issues since purpose is to show use of writeObject/ readObject methods.

Comment: That doesn't answer the other part. Why are the `readObject` and `writeObject` methods private?