# Java write a byte array with given ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, deserialization, eofexception

I have a **serializable class** with custom **writeObject()** and **readObject()** methods.
When an object serializes, it needs to write **two** byte arrays, one after another. When something deserializes it, it needs to **read** those two arrays.

This is my code:

```
private void writeObject (final ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    ..
    out.writeByte(this.signature.getV());    //one byte
    out.writeObject(this.signature.getR());  //an array of bytes
    out.writeObject(this.signature.getS());  //an array of bytes
    out.close();
}

private void readObject (final ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ..
    v = in.readByte();
    r = (byte[])in.readObject();
    s = (byte[])in.readObject();
    this.signature = new Sign.SignatureData(v, r, s);    //creating a new object because
                                                         //sign.signaturedata
                                                         // is not serializable
    in.close();
}
```

When the object is being deserialized (readObject method) it throws an **EOFException** and all three variables are **null/undefined**.

Relating to question title, I saw a class called **ByteArrayOutputStream**, but to use it, it has to be enclosed in a ObjectOutputStream, which I cannot do, ad I have an OutputStream given and must write with it.

**1.** How do one properly write a byte array using objectOutputStream and properly reads it using ObjectInputStream?

**2.** Why the code above throws an **EOFException** without reading even one variable?

**EDIT:** I need to clarify: the **readObject()** and **writeObject()** are called by jvm itself while deserializing and serializing the object.
The second thing is, the SignatureData is a subclass to Sign, that comes from a third-party library - and that's why it's not serializable.

The third thing is, the problem probably lies in the reading and writing byte arrays by ObjectInput/ObjectOutput streams, not in the Sign.SignatureData class.

Comment: Can you share the actual call of those methods?

Comment: @Gaurav writeObject and readObject are called by jvm internally on the object of serialized class

Comment: But why they are privately defined?

Comment: @GauravSrivastav, they must be private. There's [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7467313/479288) with answers on why this is required.

Comment: *First*, don't close the streams in the serialization methods, because you didn't open them there. Leave it to the caller to do it. *Second*, I tried to reproduce your problem but it worked for me. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).